# Splitting a string into multiple lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

How would I go further reducing a list which has been formed using splitlines into smaller lists?

For instance:

I have a string such as `'abc,def,hij\nklm,nop,qrs\ntuv,wx,yz\n'`
Which when using splitlines becomes
`['abc,def,hij' , 'klm,nop,qrs' , 'tuv,wx,yz']`

How can I then take this and split it up by commas, so that each element is a string element. 
such as:
`['abc','def','hij'] ['klm','nop','qrs'] ['tuv','wx','yz']`

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s = 'abc,def,hij\nklm,nop,qrs\ntuv,wx,yz\n'
>>> [l.split(',') for l in s.split('\n') if l]
[['abc','def','hij'] ['klm','nop','qrs'] ['tuv','wx','yz']]
```